# Pattern matching of exception names

Tags: elixir

I'm exploring Elixir and have a doubt. Suppose I have code like this:

```
defmodule Drop2 do
    def fall_velocity(planemo, distance) do
        gravity = case planemo do
            :earth -> 9.8
            :moon -> 1.6
            :mars -> 3.71
        end
        :math.sqrt(2 * gravity * distance)
    end
end
```

And I pass a negative number as `distance` to make the function fail:

```
iex(8)> Drop2.fall_velocity(:earth, -20)
** (ArithmeticError) bad argument in arithmetic expression
    (stdlib) :math.sqrt(-392.0)
             drop2.ex:9: Drop2.fall_velocity/2
```

This can be made better by adding exception handling:

```
defmodule Drop2 do
    def fall_velocity(planemo, distance) do
        try do
            gravity = case planemo do
                :earth -> 9.8
                :moon -> 1.6
                :mars -> 3.71
            end
            :math.sqrt(2 * gravity * distance)
        rescue
            ArithmeticError -> {:error, "Distance must be non-negative number"}
            CaseClauseError -> {:error, "Unknown planemo: #{planemo}"}
        end
    end
end
```

And now we have:

```
iex(9)> Drop2.fall_velocity(:earth, -20)
{:error, "Distance must be non-negative number"}
```

Great, but I don't see how the pattern `ArithmeticError` matches. In the previous example, the exception generated was mostly text, with `(ArithmeticError)` wrapped in parenthesis. It's not the usual pattern matching in Elixir. How is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the previous example, the exception generated was mostly text, with (ArithmeticError) wrapped in parenthesis.

The exception was not text, it was just that `iex` was printing a text representation of the exception instead of the exact value ([source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/683a847f64c0ca4cf8c2317642cb409496d8c53a/lib/iex/lib/iex/evaluator.ex#L112-L115)). Here's the exact exception:

```
iex(1)> try do
...(1)>   :math.sqrt(-1)
...(1)> rescue
...(1)>   e -> e
...(1)> end
%ArithmeticError{message: "bad argument in arithmetic expression"}
```

It's a struct `ArithmeticError` with a `message` field and as mentioned in the docs of [Kernel.SpecialForms.try/1](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#try/1):

> ### Rescue clauses
>
> Besides relying on pattern matching, rescue clauses provides some conveniences around exceptions that allows one to rescue an exception by its name.

Comment: `[. . .] allows one to rescue an exception by its name`: So it's a convenience. Thanks!